# change the row background-image width without effecting the max width of the row

Tags: html, css

[its like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9fME.jpg)   [it needs to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvcco.png) I am trying to change the background-image width without affecting the max width of the whole row.

i have tried different size properties but the max width of the row is 80% i only need the background-image with a max width of 100%.

this the selector/rule for the row:

```
.et_pb_row {

    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    margin: auto;

}
```

and this the selector/rule for the background-image of the row:

```
.et_pb_row_0 {

    background-size: contain;
    background-position: top right;
    background-image: url(http://fordent.uk.w3pcloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/GettyImages-532174359.jpg);

}
```

Comment: try using background image in pseudo element of parent

Comment: You can not display a background image outside of the dimensions of an element - so much should be obvious. What might be the best way to solve this - depends on the specifics. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Here check the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xwgb8tpL/)
 here i have set position relative to `body` in your case that could be the parent div of `.et_pb_row` to which you have given `width: 80%;` and setting a pseudo element to that `::after` in that i have provided `background-image`
Hope this helps.